# Unity Game Crashing after build in some systems

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I have been facing issue with Unity Build. I am testing my build in 5 system having windows 7 OS. It is working in 3 systems but NOT working in 2 systems and producing crashing report.

I tried reducing the quality to lowest possible, removing all heavy meshes etc, but still it is creating issues.

Here is my log after crash.

> Crash!!! SymInit: Symbol-SearchPath:
>   '.;C:\Users\PC_14\Documents\Received
>   Files\TestExe;C:\Users\PC_14\Documents\Received
>   Files\TestExe;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;SRV*C:\websymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;',
>   symOptions: 530, UserName: 'PC_14' OS-Version: 6.1.7601 (Service Pack
>   1) 0x100-0x1 C:\Users\PC_14\Documents\Received
>   Files\TestExe\RG_Simulator.exe:RG_Simulator.exe (01180000), size:
>   16891904 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Users\PC_14\Documents\Received Files\TestExe\RG_Simulator.exe',
>   fileVersion: 5.1.2.53814 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll:ntdll.dll
>   (77150000), size: 1294336 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.18247
>   C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll:kernel32.dll (75C80000), size: 868352
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.18409
>   C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll:KERNELBASE.dll (75240000), size:
>   307200 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.18409
>   C:\Windows\system32\HID.DLL:HID.DLL (73870000), size: 36864 (result:
>   0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\system32\HID.DLL',
>   fileVersion: 6.1.7600.16385 C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll:msvcrt.dll
>   (759A0000), size: 704512 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll', fileVersion: 7.0.7601.17744
>   C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll:WS2_32.dll (772F0000), size: 217088
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.17514
>   C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll:RPCRT4.dll (75560000), size: 663552
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.18532
>   C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll:NSI.dll (75C00000), size: 24576 (result:
>   0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll',
>   fileVersion: 6.1.7600.16385 C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll:USER32.dll
>   (76430000), size: 823296 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.17514
>   C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll:GDI32.dll (77330000), size: 319488
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.18577
>   C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll:LPK.dll (75700000), size: 40960 (result:
>   0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll',
>   fileVersion: 6.1.7601.18177 C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll:USP10.dll
>   (75710000), size: 643072 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll', fileVersion: 1.626.7601.18454
>   C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll:VERSION.dll (74650000), size: 36864
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7600.16385
>   C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll:ole32.dll (75F80000), size: 1425408
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.17514
>   C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll:SHLWAPI.dll (77290000), size: 356352
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.17514
>   C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll:ADVAPI32.dll (754C0000), size: 655360
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.18247
>   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll:sechost.dll (75C10000), size: 102400
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7600.16385
>   C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll:SHELL32.dll (76500000), size: 12886016
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.18517
>   C:\Windows\system32\OPENGL32.dll:OPENGL32.dll (51A20000), size: 819200
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\OPENGL32.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7600.16385
>   C:\Windows\system32\GLU32.dll:GLU32.dll (53950000), size: 139264
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\GLU32.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7600.16385
>   C:\Windows\system32\DDRAW.dll:DDRAW.dll (524F0000), size: 946176
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\DDRAW.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7600.16385
>   C:\Windows\system32\DCIMAN32.dll:DCIMAN32.dll (725B0000), size: 24576
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\DCIMAN32.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.18177
>   C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll:SETUPAPI.dll (76200000), size:
>   1691648 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.17514
>   C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll:CFGMGR32.dll (75360000), size: 159744
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.17514
>   C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll:OLEAUT32.dll (763A0000), size: 585728
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.17676
>   C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll:DEVOBJ.dll (75220000), size: 73728
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7600.16385
>   C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll:dwmapi.dll (73850000), size: 77824
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7600.16385
>   C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll:WINMM.dll (73300000), size: 204800
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.17514
>   C:\Windows\system32\MSACM32.dll:MSACM32.dll (73250000), size: 81920
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\MSACM32.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7600.16385
>   C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.dll:IMM32.dll (75980000), size: 126976
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.17514
>   C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll:MSCTF.dll (76130000), size: 835584
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7600.16385
>   C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll:DNSAPI.dll (74A30000), size: 278528
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.17570
>   C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL:IPHLPAPI.DLL (72E20000), size: 114688
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.17514
>   C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL:WINNSI.DLL (72E10000), size: 28672
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL', fileVersion: 6.1.7600.16385
>   C:\Windows\system32\WINHTTP.dll:WINHTTP.dll (72C30000), size: 360448
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\WINHTTP.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.17514
>   C:\Windows\system32\webio.dll:webio.dll (728C0000), size: 323584
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-nosymbols-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\webio.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.17725
>   C:\Users\PC_14\Documents\Received
>   Files\TestExe\RG_Simulator_Data\Mono\mono.dll:mono.dll (10000000),
>   size: 2293760 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Users\PC_14\Documents\Received
>   Files\TestExe\RG_Simulator_Data\Mono\mono.dll', fileVersion: 1.0.0.1
>   C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL:PSAPI.DLL (760E0000), size: 20480
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL', fileVersion: 6.1.7600.16385
>   C:\Windows\system32\MSWSOCK.dll:MSWSOCK.dll (74B70000), size: 245760
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\MSWSOCK.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.18254
>   C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll:CRYPTBASE.dll (75090000), size:
>   49152 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7600.16385
>   C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll:uxtheme.dll (73D20000), size: 262144
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7600.16385
>   C:\Windows\system32\d3d9.dll:d3d9.dll (71EE0000), size: 1847296
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\d3d9.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.17514
>   C:\Windows\system32\d3d8thk.dll:d3d8thk.dll (72540000), size: 24576
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\d3d8thk.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7600.16385
>   C:\Windows\system32\igdumdx32.dll:igdumdx32.dll (04320000), size:
>   544768 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\igdumdx32.dll', fileVersion: 8.14.10.1930
>   C:\Windows\system32\igdumd32.dll:igdumd32.dll (05A30000), size:
>   3895296 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\igdumd32.dll', fileVersion: 8.14.10.1930
>   C:\Windows\system32\DXGIDebug.dll:DXGIDebug.dll (6BF30000), size:
>   114688 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\DXGIDebug.dll', fileVersion: 9.30.9600.17029
>   C:\Windows\system32\WINTRUST.dll:WINTRUST.dll (75290000), size: 188416
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\WINTRUST.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.18205
>   C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll:CRYPT32.dll (753A0000), size: 1179648
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.18277
>   C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll:MSASN1.dll (751A0000), size: 49152
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.17514
>   C:\Windows\system32\MMDevAPI.DLL:MMDevAPI.DLL (74450000), size: 233472
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\MMDevAPI.DLL', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.17514
>   C:\Windows\system32\PROPSYS.dll:PROPSYS.dll (74320000), size: 1003520
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\PROPSYS.dll', fileVersion: 7.0.7601.17514
>   C:\Windows\system32\wdmaud.drv:wdmaud.drv (732D0000), size: 196608
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\wdmaud.drv', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.17514
>   C:\Windows\system32\ksuser.dll:ksuser.dll (732C0000), size: 16384
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\ksuser.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7600.16385
>   C:\Windows\system32\AVRT.dll:AVRT.dll (74420000), size: 28672 (result:
>   0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\system32\AVRT.dll',
>   fileVersion: 6.1.7600.16385
>   C:\Windows\system32\AUDIOSES.DLL:AUDIOSES.DLL (73280000), size: 221184
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\AUDIOSES.DLL', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.17514
>   C:\Windows\system32\msacm32.drv:msacm32.drv (73270000), size: 32768
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\msacm32.drv', fileVersion: 6.1.7600.16385
>   C:\Windows\system32\midimap.dll:midimap.dll (73240000), size: 28672
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\midimap.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7600.16385
>   C:\Windows\system32\dsound.dll:dsound.dll (69440000), size: 466944
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\dsound.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7600.16385
>   C:\Windows\system32\POWRPROF.dll:POWRPROF.dll (74490000), size: 151552
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\POWRPROF.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7600.16385
>   C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL:CLBCatQ.DLL (75670000), size: 536576
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL', fileVersion: 2001.12.8530.16385
>   C:\Windows\system32\xinput9_1_0.dll:xinput9_1_0.dll (725C0000), size:
>   36864 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\xinput9_1_0.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7600.16385
>   C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll:dbghelp.dll (6C0F0000), size: 962560
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.17514
>   C:\Windows\system32\SspiCli.dll:SspiCli.dll (75010000), size: 110592
>   (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB:
>   'C:\Windows\system32\SspiCli.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.18443
>
> ========== OUTPUTING STACK TRACE ==================
>
> 013FB3B0 (DUMMY_GAME) ShaderLab::FastPropertyName::Init
>
> ========== END OF STACKTRACE ===========
>
> **** Crash! ****

Please help for this issue.

Comment: Anything immeadiately before the log you posted that hints to what the game was doing? The ShaderLab in the stack indicates something to do with a shader or a resource a shader is using (eg: texture2D). Possibly your passing a bad Texture?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved. The issue lies with standard shaders in Unity 5.1. Standard shaders are unsupported to some systems (I don't know why), so I changed all the materials with Legacy shaders and everything started working fine.

Thanks...

Comment: Also, I had an issue with the Standard Bumped + Legacy Bumped shaders on some old machines. Replacing only those helped for me.